# change varibable value using mongoose query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have code blow and need to replace the "doc" (query result) with projectsDocument,
but projectsDocument not defined in the function,please help me!!!!

```
var projectsDocument, categoryDocument; //empty
    projectsModel.find({}, {}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (doc) {
            projectsDocument = doc; 

        }
    });
    console.log(projectsDocument); //want to projectsDocument be equals to doc
```

[SOLVED]

i change my code to this and it works

```
    router.get('/', async(req, res, next) => {

    await projectsModel.find().then(function(doc) {
        projectsDocument = doc;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

});
```

Comment: replace projectsDocument with doc(query result) ***

Comment: This question is not clear on what you're trying to do, try this first :: `projectsModel.find({}).toArray((err, doc) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (doc) {
            projectsDocument = doc; 

        }
    });`

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: its a async call back so `console.log(projectsDocument);` execute before callback finished .That's why its undefined . you could console.log inside the exec callback i will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Javascript is async in nature means it does not execute instructions such as API calls synchronously (does not wait for the response).

**Mongoose version > [4.0](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes)**

```
projectsModel.find()
.then(function(doc){
   if (doc) {
        projectsDocument = doc; 
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {})
```

**Mongoose version < 4.0**

```
var projects = projectsModel.find().exec() //returns promise

projects.then(function(project){
    if (project) {
       projectsDocument = project;
    }
})
```

Comment: i have tried this but nothing happend!

Comment: @AmirMohammadRivand What you are getting in the `doc`?

Comment: clearly query result as Object

Comment: which version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: i use mongoose ver 5.*

Comment: @AmirMohammadRivand That's strange, even with first approach you are getting same problem?

Did you try `console.log(doc)` to check if `doc` has a an object?

Comment: thank you! it is working

Comment: What was the issue? You can thank me by accepting the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: you can see my new code at the top

Comment: cool, Happy it helped :)